# How to balance all volume in one action in a sound, in Adobe Audition?

Tags: adobe-audition

I'm new to Adobe Audition. I'm not a sound expert. I just record my voice with a microphone for a podcast, then using Adobe Audition, I try to make it better as much as I can, then I'll post it.

Now, the point is, after each pause, I start a new sentence, or a new paragraph with apparent energy. This makes that part of my voice be recorded in higher decibels.

[image]

Thus I have to select those parts after each pause manually, and using `dB` tool reduce it's amplitude. This is very tedious, error-prone and non-uniform of course.

Since I lack terminology, I can't find a solution for reducing the entire sound to a max limit (less than red zone of highness in volume). I searched for *How to reduce volume for an entire sound in Adobe Audition*, or *How to smooth out decibels in Adobe Audition*. But no success.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The tools you are looking for are a compressor, &/or limiter.
One will reduce sound gently if it crosses a specified threshold; the other will prevent any signal exceeding your set threshold. Judicious use of both in-line could tame your voice track.
I don't know Audition, but most apps these days would come with basic versions of both, built-in.

Long-term, though, what you need is **practise**.
Voice-over is a skill, same as any other. You need to be aware of how loud or forceful your voice is at all times & be able to control your own levels. You also need good awareness of mic distance, to prevent proximity effect changing over time.

Comment: your last recommendations are truly insightful

Comment: There's a 'trick' you can try. if you make a mistake or need to re-do any section, start by re-reading the end of the previous section, so you're not coming in 'brand new fresh', you've had a few seconds to settle in.